# Switching user asks for password again when exiting

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to switch users with my Python code. However, when I try to exit, I get the following and press ctrl-z to close the program:

> someuser:~$ exit
>   exit
>   Password:
>   [4]+  Stopped                 python3 loginTest.py

My code is below:

```
import subprocess
import getpass

userNameInput = input("\n" + "Please enter your username." + "\n")

login = subprocess.run(['su', '-p', userNameInput], stdin=True)
stdin = subprocess.Popen([getpass.getpass() + "\n"])
```

Why am I being asked for my password again? Is it because the subprocess.run() is waiting for the program to exit?

Comment: The program you have given does not produce the output given

Comment: @IainShelvington, if it matters, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in Windows System Linux.

Comment: I fixed the variables. I had messed them up in cutting down my code for this post.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ctrl+C vs Ctrl+Z

You probably want to use Ctrl+C instead to kill the process.

Ctrl+Z will put the process into the background, and you should only use it if you *mean* to [bg](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubg.htm) a process. If you do this routinely on the CLI and don't restart your machine, you could bog down your system with zombie processes. If you use Ctrl+Z to "kill" a process, you will get unexpected behavior.

#### The difference

Ask Ubuntu has a decent answer on [the difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal) between Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z.

Comment: This is irrelevant and does not answer the question.